# sumif where row range is determined by another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I have the following formula:
=sumif(Gx:Gy,50,Px:Py)
where x and y are numbers I have entered.

However, I want the numbers in the above formula to be determined by the values in another cell (let's say the x to be determined by the value in cell A1, and the y to be determined by the value in cell A2). So if A1 contained 3 and A2 contained 5 then the formula would be =sumif(G3:G5,50,P3:P5). How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `SUMIF` and `INDIRECT`

The formula in F6 below is:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("A"&F9&":A"&G9),50,INDIRECT("B"&F9&":B"&G9))
```

[image: sumif indirect]

Comment: You are a legend, thank you very much, this was perfect :D

Comment: No worries, happy to help! Please mark this as the chosen answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: I definitely did do that, but since my reputation is less than 15, it doesn't show up publicly :( - edit: whoops i actually didn't, but i did now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use OFFSET

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(G1,A1,,A2-A1,1),50,OFFSET(P1,A1,,A2-A1,1))
```

[image: Data]

You probably want some handling to ensure X<=Y.

That might look like:

```
=IF(A1<=A2,SUMIF(OFFSET(G1,A1,,A2-A1,1),50,OFFSET(P1,A1,,A2-A1,1)),"")
```

Comment: Cheers buddy :)